# Create an N length array with pre-filled column names

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

My aim is to create an array having N length with pre filled column names with `PHP`. Here is an example,

```
if N = 5; then
$test_array = array('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5');
```

I tried `array_fill` function, but the array values are same. Can someone suggest me a better method ?

Update

This is how it looks while using `array_fill`. I know, i can use `foreach` and solve this within a fraction of seconds, what i'm searching for a one line method; if exists.

```
<?php
$n = 5;
$test_array = array_fill(0, $n, 'column');
echo print_r($test_array, true);
?>
```

Result : Array ( [0] => column [1] => column [2] => column [3] => column [4] => column )

Comment: What is your expected output. Post your attempts too

Comment: And what is your expected output

Comment: array('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5');

Comment: So what about [`@arkascha's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33008435/2899618)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for, considering you wrote of "column names" to be prefilled:

```
<?php
$test_array = [];
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $test_array['column'.$i] = null;
}
var_dump($test_array);
```

This will create this output:

```
array(5) {
  'column0' => NULL
  'column1' => NULL
  'column2' => NULL
  'column3' => NULL
  'column4' => NULL
}
```

If instead you are looking for "column values", so array elements being prefilled, then try that:

```
<?php
$test_array = [];
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $test_array[] = 'column'.$i;
}
var_dump($test_array);
```

That will create this output:

```
array(5) {
  0 => 'column0'
  1 => 'column1'
  2 => 'column2'
  3 => 'column3'
  4 => 'column4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Php an array is dynamic at all . You don't need to set its length.. As per your need you may create an array to serve as key(column names) and then combine it to values containing array . Try follwing -

```
    $column_array=array('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5');
    $value_array=array('a','b','c','d','e');
    $reslut=array_combine($column_array,$value_array);
    print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [column1] => a [column2] => b [column3] => c [column4] => d [column5] => e )
```

array_combine needs both array have same length . As your condition stays ,it may be some columns might ave null values .To work in that condition do as follow-

```
    $column_array=array('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5');
    $value_array=array('a','b','c','d');
    $value_array +=array_fill(
                            count($value_array),
                            count($column_array)-
                            count($value_array),null);
                            //filling array upto column array length
    $result=array_combine($column_array,$value_array);
    print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
 Array ( [column1] => a [column2] => b [column3] => c [column4] => d [column5] => )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = [];
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $array['column'.$i] = null;
}
die($array);
?>
```